# 2-Dimensions Integral convergence

Tags: calculus, integration, convergence-divergence

Does the following integral converge on $\mathbb{R}^2$: $\int \int \frac{log(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2}dxdy$

I found that inside the unit circle the integral is -$\infty$ and outside the unit circle its +$\infty$. Can I conclude anything about the convergence of the integral from that? If not, what do I need to do?

Comment: You conclude that the original integral is divergent (too strong singularity at the origin, and decays to slowly at infinity). What do you mean by "Where do I go from here?"?

Comment: I don't understand, can you elaborate please?